# fetch data is updated but array and state is not updated

Tags: reactjs

i am woking on weather api and storing perticular data in an array arr but value is not available in arr. also state  arrdata is null too.
i tried to not use state but still not getting data in arr . it show reading undefined value.

```
export default function App() {
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState("delhi");
  const [arrData, setArrData] = useState(null);
  const getWeatherInfo = async () => {
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";
    const api = "4beffc863037e89f0f181d893d1cf79b";
     fetch(`${url}?q=${cityName}&units=metric&appid=${api}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((getData) => {     
      if(getData.list[4].main !== null){
        const arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= 40; i++) {
          if (i % 8 === 0) {
            arr.push({
              temprature: getData.list[i].main.temp,
              Min_temp: getData.list[i].main.temp_min,
              Max_temp: getData.list[i].main.temp_max,
              date: getData.list[i].dt_txt,
              mood: getData.list[i].weather[0].main,
              weathermoodIcon: getData.list[i].weather[0].icon,
              Humidity: getData.list[i].main.humidity,
            });
          }}
        setArrData(arr);
      }});
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getWeatherInfo()
  }, []);
 console.log(arrData)
  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setCityName(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmitCity = () => {
    getWeatherInfo();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input onChangeValue={onInputChange} onSubmit={onSubmitCity} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working. Please do not forget to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
export default function App() {
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState("delhi");
  const [arrData, setArrData] = useState(null);
  const getWeatherInfo = async () => {
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";
    const api = "4beffc863037e89f0f181d893d1cf79b";
     fetch(`${url}?q=${cityName}&units=metric&appid=${api}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((getData) => {     
      if(getData.list[40]?.main !== null){
        const arr = [];
        console.log(getData.list)
        for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
          if (i % 8 === 0) {
            arr.push({
              temprature: getData.list[i]?.main.temp,
              Min_temp: getData.list[i]?.main.temp_min,
              Max_temp: getData.list[i]?.main.temp_max,
              date: getData.list[i]?.dt_txt,
              mood: getData.list[i]?.weather[0].main,
              weathermoodIcon: getData.list[i]?.weather[0].icon,
              Humidity: getData.list[i]?.main.humidity,
            });
          }}
        setArrData(arr);
      }});
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getWeatherInfo();
  
  }, []);

 console.log(arrData)
  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setCityName(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmitCity = () => {
    getWeatherInfo();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input  onChange={onInputChange} onSubmit={onSubmitCity} />
      <h1> {JSON.stringify(arrData)} </h1>
      <button onClick = {onSubmitCity}> Submit </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, its working. problem was i need to use ? after list

Comment: @HowtoProgram you are welcome!! yes, I believe so, but still feel free to play with that to understand the problem. Cheers!!

Comment: what is use of JSON.stringify here ?

Comment: @HowtoProgram because result is an array of objects, so you may need to map it or will get an error when rendering. So, just to visualize the array, it is convenient to convert it to string using ``JSON.stringify`` .  You still need to map it if you want to do more things with it.